# How to start minix

Tags: minix

I installed minix in VirtualBox but I don't know whether it installed correctly or not. Just check this screen shot and let me know how to test it.

[image: Screenshot]

This is the result when i am trying to login as root:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to log in. (Try user: `root` . There should be no password.) [Post installation documentation](http://wiki.minix3.org/en/UsersGuide/PostInstallation)

Comment: check edit part. when i am trying to login as root its not asking for password

Comment: Yeah because there is NO root password. You can set one with using `passwd`. Thats all. You are in the minix already when you see the `$`. :)

Answer (score 0):

Log in with root, test some basic Unix commands.

Add a user, switch to using that user except for administrative tasks.

If you don't get any problems doing this, you have it installed right. In fact, if you can log in as root, you almost definitely have it installed right. Good job!